# como pasar datos de una tabla a otra en sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql

buen día. la cuestión es la siguiente. me pasaron un excel con ciertos datos de productos, lo que importa es la cantidad. yo en sql grabe los datos de ese excel en una tabla temporal, ahora necesitaría que se migren esos datos de tabla temporal a la tabla real de productos. Ejemplo:

si el producto de cada tabla coincide que se grabe la cantidad de la temporal en la tabla real. (los campos se llaman iguales!

Comment: Y que intentaste? esto es un insert o un update?

Comment: Deberías mostrar al menos la estructura de la tabla

Comment: No es claro lo que solicita

Answer (score 1):

Asumiendo la siguiente estructura de tablas:

```
create table Temporal(
idproducto int,
cantidad int
);

create table Productos(
idproducto int,
cantidad int
);
```

La actualización podría hacerse así:

```
update Productos
set cantidad = (select cantidad from Temporal t where t.idproducto = Productos.idproducto)
```

Comment: gracias crrlos me remil sirvió!

Answer (score 1):

Mi opción que te doy es crear un procedimiento almacenado, donde crees unas variables donde se alojarán los campos de cada registro.

Te pondré un caso de ejemplo:
Tengo una tabla temporal con el mismo nombre, y vamos pasar los datos a la tabla transferencias.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEMPORAL_IV](
[id_temp_dia] INT NULL,
[hora_temp] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[puerta_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[id_tar_temp] INT NULL,
[usuario_temp] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[desc_dep_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[id_dep_temp] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[doc_usu_temp] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[mensaje_temp] [nvarchar](80) NULL,
[num_tar_us_temp] [text] NULL,
[fecha_temp] [date] NULL);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TRANSFERENCIAS_IV](
[id_trans] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[id_trans_dia] [int] NULL,
[hora_trans] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[puerta_trans] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[id_tar_trans] [int] NULL,
[usuario_trans] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[desc_dep_trans] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[id_dep_trans] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[doc_usu_trans] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
[mensaje_trans] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[num_tar_us_trans] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
[fecha_trans] date NULL);
```

Creamos las variables para almacenar los campos de la BD

```
    DECLARE @id INT, @hora nvarchar(20), @puerta nvarchar(20), @idTarjeta INT, @usuario nvarchar(100), 
 @departamento nvarchar(30), @idDep nvarchar(20), @nit nvarchar(20), @mensaje nvarchar(200), 
 @tarjeta nvarchar(30),@fecha date
```

Creamos un cursor para obtener filas de la tabla.

```
declare idat cursor for select id_temp_dia, hora_temp, puerta_temp, id_tar_temp, usuario_temp, desc_dep_temp, id_dep_temp, doc_usu_temp,
mensaje_temp, num_tar_us_temp, fecha_temp FROM TEMPORAL_IV;
```

y luego con un ciclo recorreremos con el cursor la tabla para insertar registro por registro

```
OPEN idat
--EN esta línea, instanciamos el cursor para que las variables obtenga los datos de la misma.
FETCH NEXT FROM idat INTO @id, @hora, @puerta, @idTarjeta, @usuario, @departamento, @idDep, @nit, @mensaje, @tarjeta, @fecha
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN 
--Insertamos los datos y listo, el fetch nos lleva a la línea siguiente.    
 INSERT INTO TRANSFERENCIAS_IV (id_trans_dia,hora_trans,puerta_trans,id_tar_trans,usuario_trans,desc_dep_trans,id_dep_trans,doc_usu_trans,mensaje_trans,num_tar_us_trans,fecha_trans)
 VALUES (@id,@hora,@puerta,@idTarjeta,@usuario,@departamento,@idDep,@nit,@mensaje,@tarjeta,@fecha);
FETCH NEXT FROM idat INTO @id,@hora,@puerta,@idTarjeta,@usuario,@departamento,@idDep,@nit,@mensaje,@tarjeta,@fecha
END
CLOSE idat
DEALLOCATE idat
```

Lo único que debes de tener en cuenta es: Que las tablas deben de tener los mismos parámetros, al igual de las variables que  instancies.

Comment: hola man tambien me sirvó pero es distinto a lo que yo necesitaba, debajo otro usuario dió al clavo!